# Responsive div contents

Tags: html, css

I have made a `div` called `#work`. Inside `#work` is another `div` called `.item`. The thing is that I want to make my `div` `#work` responsive. I have tried everything to achieve my goal but all in vain. My code is given below:

HTML:

```
<div id="work"> <!-- Work Links Section Start -->

                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="air-ticket.php"><img src="images/work/thumbs/air.jpg" alt="Air Ticket"></a><!-- Image must be 400px by 300px -->
                          <h3>Air Ticketing</h3><!--Title-->
                            <!--Category-->
                        </div><!--/item-->

                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="hotelbook.php"><img src="images/work/thumbs/hotelbook.jpg" alt="Hotel Booking"></a><!-- Image must be 400px by 300px -->
                          <h3>Hotel Booking</h3><!--Title-->
                            <!--Category-->
                        </div><!--/item-->
```

The CSS:

```
#work{
width:930px;
max-width:100%;
position: relative;
margin:0 auto;
line-height: 1.4em;
border:1px solid #000;
}

.item{
border-radius:9px;
width:263px;
max-width:100%;
height:220px;
background-color:#FFF;
margin:15px;
float:left;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #c3c3c3;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #c3c3c3;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #c3c3c3;  
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.item:hover{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #f38094, 0 0 8px #f38094;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #f38094,  0 0 8px #f38094;
box-shadow: 0 0 8px #f38094,  0 0 8px #f38094; 
}
```

Comment: seems to me like the responsiveness is just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/uat64xzq/1/ what's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Following link include CSS media rule. You can determine CSS rule for screen size.
[W3 Schools CSS @media Rule](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: Thaank you for your support. I have another question related to responsiveness of my page. could you please help me out.